# How to display a string value in a Calendar control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I have a string value which is in DateTime format where I have captured from a different Calendar control; How can I display that value in a Calendar control in a asp.net form?

```
string dateTo = dsDept.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
string datefrom = dsDept.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
```

Two string values are selected from a data grid view. I need these two dates to be displayed in two Calendar controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert that to `DateTime` and then assign to calendar `SelectedDate` property like

```
  DateTime capturedDate;
  if(DateTime.TryParse(dateTo, out capturedDate))
    {
       Calendar1.SelectedDate = capturedDate;
    }
```

Comment: Although the code doesn't generate any errors ; it doesn't highlight the date which is in string format. Any suggestions?